# Error Initializing ADB Unable to create Debug Bridge Unable to start ADB server Process didn't terminate within specified timeout killing it server

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, adb, android-sdk-tools

In Android Studio were it was supposed to show physical device list it keeps saying **Loading Devices..**.I tried every possible answers I found online, killing ADB from task manager, reinstalling platform tool, reinstalling android studio, manually running ADB, starting ADB server manually, even starting android studio as admin. I removed anti-virus. But nothing is working.
Problem here is that when I run the **adb devices** it is able to detect my phone but android studio doesn't.
NOTE: I have my phone on in debug mode, with file transfer permission.

[here is a screen shot of android studio, and the cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmhlB.jpg)